# mvn not able to get JAVA_HOME in mac

Tags: macos, maven

I am using macOs And I have set JAVA_HOME in ~/.zshrc file, Even I have checked the `echo $JAVA_HOME` and its showing correct path.

macOs version: Monterey
After this mvn is giving error.(maven version 3.8.4)

```
yogendrasingh@197NODMB29073 code % mvn -version
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue with maven 3.9.1. My JAVA_HOME is defined correctly in .zshrc but still maven is not able to find it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting `JAVA_HOME` like this in your `~/.zshrc` file:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

And don't forget to execute `source ~/.zshrc` or to restart your shell afterwards

Answer (score -1):

Do you have other versions of Java and Maven installed? Maybe try reinstalling both of them.

Comment: No I am using binary version only.

Comment: Please provide the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME`. It should point to the root of the installation dir and not to the bin/ subfolder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).